# show progressbar when database copying

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In the first run of my app, i have to copy database file to data folder. it takes about 10 sec and in this period of time user sees a black screen. I want to use AsynTask technique to show a progressbar. but it doesnt work an i see that progressbar after black screen goes away...

with this code i call copy database class and also i call AsynTsk process...

```
    new asyn().execute();
    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
```

and this is my AsynTask code:

```
    public class asyn extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
      ProgressDialog dialog;  
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute()
      {  
        //loading toast
            //final DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
            String firstload2 = myDbHelper.getfirstload();
            if(firstload2.matches("1")) {
                 dialog=new ProgressDialog(DictionaryActivity.this);
                   dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                   dialog.setMax(100);
                   dialog.show();
                myDbHelper.changefirstload();
            }



      }  
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
       // perform desired task in this doInBackground Block.
       for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
       {
        publishProgress(5);
        try {
         Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }

       return "";
      }
      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onProgressUpdate(values);
       dialog.incrementProgressBy(5);   
       }

      @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result)
      {
        dialog.dismiss();    
       AlertDialog.Builder a=new Builder(DictionaryActivity.this);
       a.setMessage("Successfully Done");
       a.setTitle("Try");
       a.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
       a.show();
          }  
     }
```

where is my fault? how i can fix that?

Answer (score 1):

`myDbHelper.changefirstload();` should be within the `doInBackground()` method. `onPreExecute()` executes on the UI thread.

In terms of a progress bar, that's a bit difficult here. Personally, I'd do an indeterminate progress bar (just a spinning icon or something while it loads). If you want to have a % bar, though, you will need to break up the method into multiple methods, then update your progress in between them.